# XmlSerializer and factory-created elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, factory-pattern, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize/deserialize objects that have factory-created members. For example, lets say there are a member of type `Foo`, which is instantiated using FooFactory.CreateFoo(int bar).

My current idea is to

1.create a custom XmlReader (for example, derive from XmlTextReader), and attach the factory to it

2.implement IXmlSerializable

3.in ReadXml(), I can the grab the factory from the reader.

Not sure if this is the most elegant way to do it, has anybody made similar attempts ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` simply isn't set up for that. I would strongly suggest that if you want to use `XmlSerializer`, your best bet would be to map your data to a simpler DTO model **first**, and serialize *that*. When writing code back from the DTO to your model, add the factory creation *there*, in regular code. The DTO model should be simple; simple enough for `XmlSerializer` to be happy with it.

Yes, implementing `IXmlSerializable` is *an* option, however: that API is **very** hard to get 100% right (to handle all the various ways xml can appear to it). I find that API very hard, and I do a lot of serialization. I humbly submit that writing a few lines of code to map from your *main* model to a DTO model is a lot more robust (and a lot quicker) than trying to implement `IXmlSerializable`.

For example, you could have:

```
[XmlRoot("foo")]
public class FooDTO {
     [XmlAttribute("bar")]
     public int Bar {get;set;}

     public static implicit operator Foo(FooDTO value)
     {
         return value == null ? null : FooFactory.Create(value.Bar);
     }
     public static implicit operator FooDTO(Foo value)
     {
         return value == null ? null : new FooDTO { Bar = value.Bar; }
     }
}
```

then you can convert from `Foo` to `FooDTO` simply by:

```
Foo foo = ...
FooDTO dto = foo;
```

Comment: Thanks, DTO seems to be the way to go here ! :)